# Model between-subject condition as population effect or random intercept?

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model

I have an experiment where participants were assigned to one of four conditions (between-subject), and I want to predict a binary outcome (`is_correct`). Each participant answered one question so no repeated measures. So far I have come up with two models written in `lme4`-style formula syntax:

```
# condition as population effect
is_correct ~ condition

# condition as random intercept
is_correct ~ 1 + (1 | condition)
```

Which formulation should I use if I want to compare those conditions and determine which condition helps participants get more answers correct? I plan to fit a Bayesian GLM in `brms`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in your first model:

> ```
> is_correct ~ condition
> ```

..this is not a mixed model, you are fitting fixed effects for condition and there are no random effects.

In your second model:

> ```
> is_correct ~ 1 + (1 | condition)
> ```

...this is a mixed model where you are controlling for clustering within `condition`. However, since you only have 4 conditions, it seems likely that the first model will be better.